# LabelEncoding Multiple Categorical Columns

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a DataFrame with a mix of int, float, categorical and bool datatype and I am trying to convert the categorical and bool ones to int using LabelEncoder.fit_transform. When perform on a single column, it works perfectly well however when I try to do a for loop through the DF, I have the following error:

```
relabel = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
for i in first_buyer.columns:
    if str(first_buyer[i].dtypes) not in ["float64","int64","bool"]:
        first_buyer[i] = relabel.fit_transform(first_buyer[i])
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py in _encode(values, uniques, encode)
    104         try:
--> 105             res = _encode_python(values, uniques, encode)
    106         except TypeError:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py in _encode_python(values, uniques, encode)
     58     if uniques is None:
---> 59         uniques = sorted(set(values))
     60         uniques = np.array(uniques, dtype=values.dtype)

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-42e60975f0b6> in <module>
      4 for i in first_buyer.columns:
      5     if str(first_buyer[i].dtypes) not in ["float64","int64","bool"]:
----> 6         first_buyer[i] = relabel.fit_transform(first_buyer[i])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py in fit_transform(self, y)
    234         """
    235         y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
--> 236         self.classes_, y = _encode(y, encode=True)
    237         return y
    238 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py in _encode(values, uniques, encode)
    105             res = _encode_python(values, uniques, encode)
    106         except TypeError:
--> 107             raise TypeError("argument must be a string or number")
    108         return res
    109     else:

TypeError: argument must be a string or number
```

I have tried using OneHotCoder and MultiColumnLabelEncoder class from others but they all threw me the same error

```
MultiColumnLabelEncoder(columns = [col for col in first_buyer if 
str(first_buyer[i].dtypes) not 
in["float64","int64","bool"]]).fit_transform(first_buyer)
```

I expect the output of my code will transform all categorical variable to digit so I can train my dataset

Answer (score 0):

Though I haven't seen your dataframe, it is very likely that the error will be caused by either the presence of NAs in one of the column, or by the presence of a column with mixed types.

Try this as an example:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

relabel = LabelEncoder()

# Nas in the dataframe
data1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b', 'c'] ,['1', '2', np.nan]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
# Will raise an error
relabel.fit_transform(data1['C'])

# Mixed types
data2 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b', 'c'], ['1', '2', 3]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
# Will raise an error
relabel.fit_transform(data2['C'])

# Clean data
data3 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b', 'c'], ['1', '2', '3']], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
# Will work
relabel.fit_transform(data3['C'])
```

The reason why a column with mixed types will pass your filter is that its 'dtype' is 'object'

You should do some extra preprocessing to make sure that your columns don't have missing values and are of the same type before using LabelEncoder.

You should also use a filter that is 'in' rather than 'not in' if you know all the dtypes of the columns you want to convert.

You can do this by using the fillna() and astype() methods of the columns objects:

```
# Define a dummy variable for missing values that is of the same type as the column 
data1['C'] = data1['C'].fillna('DUMMY_VARIABLE_FOR_NA')
# Will work now
relabel.fit_transform(data1['C'])

data2['C'] = data2['C'].astype(str)
# Will work now
relabel.fit_transform(data2['C'])
```